# How many primes can there be in a short interval?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Given $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let $\pi(n)$ denote the number of prime numbers $\leq n$.
What is
$$
  \limsup_{m \rightarrow \infty} \left( \limsup_{n \rightarrow \infty} \frac{\pi(n+m) - \pi(n)}{\pi(m)} \right)?
$$
If needed, answers may be conditional under the assumption that a suitable generalization
of the [Bunyakovsky conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bunyakovsky_conjecture) holds.

Comment: Hardy and Littlewood's second conjecture states $\frac{\pi(n+m)-\pi(n)}{\pi(m)} \le 1$, and so this conjecture implies that $1$ is an upper bound. (It is worth mentioning that this conjecture is incompatible with the k-tuple conjecture.) More interestingly, an unconditional upper bound $2$ follows from Montgomery and Vaughn's sieve-theoretic result that $\pi(n+m)-\pi(n) \le 2\frac{m}{\log m}$.

Comment: Which is the short interval?

Comment: @joro: $\{n+1, \dots, n+m\}$. The term *short* is of course relative here.

Comment: @OfirGorodetsky: Yes, Hardy-Littlewood is incompatible with the $k$-tuple conjecture. -- Can one tell anything *under the assumption* of the $k$-tuple conjecture?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

As observed by Hensley and Richards in

*Douglas Hensley and Ian Richards*, [**Primes in intervals**](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=396440), *Acta Arith.* **25** (1973-74), 375--391,

if the prime tuples conjecture is true, then $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \pi(n+m) - \pi(n) = \rho^*(m)$, where $\rho^*(m)$ is the length $k$ of the largest admissible $k$-tuple of diameter less than $m$ (a $k$-tuple is admissible if it avoids a residue class modulo $p$ for every prime $p$). So your quantity would then be equal to $\limsup_{m \to \infty} \rho^*(m)/\pi(m)$, which is also easily seen to be equal to $\limsup_{k \to\infty} k \log k / H(k)$, where $H(k)$ is the minimal diameter of an admissible $k$-tuple.

The best known upper and lower bounds for $H(k)$ can be found in Section 3 of [the (unabridged version of) the Polymath8a paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1402.0811v2.pdf).  The best asymptotic upper bound known is $k \log k + k \log\log k - (1+2 \log 2) k + o(k)$ (due to Schinzel), and the best asymptotic lower bound is a bit tricky to state (coming from the sharp Montgomery-Vaughan version of the large sieve) but is roughly of the form $\frac{1}{2} k \log k - o(k \log k )$.  So the best that is known about your quantity is (as was pointed out in comments) it is somewhere between $1$ and $2$.  (One does not need the best results on $H(k)$ for these bounds: the lower bound comes from observing that the first $k$ primes larger than $k$ are automatically admissible, while the upper bound follows from (the proof of) the Brun-Titchmarsh inequality.)  Based on the known numerical values and bounds for $H(k)$ (see [this online database](http://math.mit.edu/~primegaps/), as well as Figures 2 and 3 of the Polymath8a paper referenced above) one can tentatively conjecture that your quantity is equal to $1$, but the evidence is not terribly strong for this conjecture yet.  Improving the upper bound of $2$ would be a major breakthrough in sieve theory (closely related to the parity problem), and is one of the motivations of the nascent field of "inverse sieve theory", discussed in

*Ben Green and Adam J. Harper*, [**Inverse questions for the large sieve**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00039-014-0288-1), *Geom. Funct. Anal.* **24** (2014), no. 4, 1167--1203.

The upper bound of $2$ is unconditional (following directly from [Brun-Titchmarsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brun%E2%80%93Titchmarsh_theorem)).  No non-trivial unconditional lower bound (beyond the trivial bound of $0$) is known; the best result is by Maynard in

*James Maynard*, [**Small gaps between primes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4007/annals.2015.181.1.7), *Ann. of Math. (2)* **181** (2015), no. 1, 383--413

with slightly better implied constants obtained by the Polymath8b project

*D. H. J. Polymath*, [**Variants of the Selberg sieve, and bounded intervals containing many primes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1186/s40687-014-0012-7), *Res. Math. Sci.* **1** (2014), Art. 12, 83,

basically showing that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \pi(n+m) - \pi(n) \gg \log m$.  This is known to be the limit of the existing Selberg sieve method to unconditionally produce many primes in short intervals; getting beyond the $\log m$ bound here would be a significant breakthrough (though I think breaking the parity upper bound of $2$ mentioned earlier would be even more revolutionary).

Note that until the famous recent breakthrough of Zhang in

*Yitang Zhang*, [**Bounded gaps between primes**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4007/annals.2014.179.3.7), *Ann. of Math. (2)* **179** (2014), no. 3, 1121--1174.

it was not even known unconditionally that $\limsup_{n \to \infty} \pi(n+m) - \pi(n)$ was larger than $1$ for any $m$.

EDIT: Ben Green pointed out to me an observation of Selberg in Vol. I of his "Collected works" (page 610 in the new edition) that one cannot obtain effective improvements to the $1/2$ constant in the lower bound $H(k) \geq \frac{1}{2} k \log k - o(k \log k)$ without also getting effective bounds in Siegel's theorem, since a Siegel zero implies the existence of a medium-sized arithmetic progression with about twice as many primes as one would expect without the zero.  This leads to an admissible k-tuple that is also about twice as dense as expected.  So the upper bound of 2 in the original question is unlikely to be improved without some sort of breakthrough on the Siegel zero problem (or else some massive extension of the repulsion phenomenon).