# Upper bound on sum of Lambda(n) over short interval

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

I am looking for a bound of type

$$\sum_{x<n\leq x+y} \Lambda(n) \leq \frac{\log(x+y)}{\log y} \cdot 2y$$

(or better). Of course such a bound has to exist: the idea of the proof of Brun-Titchmarsh (which is more general) still applies when one considers prime powers. What I am looking for is a clean, explicit result (as clean and explicit as Brun-Titchmarsh, in the well-known Montgomery-Vaughan version) available right off the shelf.

(In particular, I do not want an error term proportional to $\sqrt{x+y}$.)

Comment: How small is your $y$ compared to $x$?

Comment: It would be best if $y$ could be allowed to be arbitrarily small (just as in Brun-Titchmarsh).

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/235463/how-many-primes-can-there-be-in-a-short-interval seems relevant. Does partial summation introduce too much error?

Comment: @CommandMaster Proving matters oneself as in Brun-Titchmarsh (sieve) would seem to make more sense. It just seems very unlikely that it hasn't been done already.

Comment: From the comments on that answer there's a known $\pi(x+y) - \pi(x) \leq 2\frac{y}{\log y}$, is that strong enough? There's some error introduced by prime powers, but it might be negligible.

Comment: I've said "Brun-Titchmarsh". Of course that has $\pi(x+y) - \pi(x) \leq 2 \frac{y}{\log y}$ as a special case!